# Solve XCode crash each time on launch after modifying an item in Build Settings

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have modified Objective-C Bridging Header with a ./ in front of file name and now it crashes every time I open it after 2 seconds. **[image: What can i do???]**
Deleting xcuserdata does nothing

**What can I do now?**